# Display all NVCC warnings in PyCUDA

Tags: cuda, pycuda

**[update]** How can I output the warning messages from `compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code)`?
With help of @flipchart I was able to pass the right parameters to NVCC trough PyCUDA, but I still don't know, where to access the compiler warnings.

**[original question]**

Using NVCC directly one can use the compiler switch `-Wall`*. How would one archive this in pycuda?

I tried `mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code,options=['-Wall'])`, but the error message states:

`pytools.prefork.ExecError: error invoking 'nvcc --cubin -Wall -arch sm_11 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycuda-0.94.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/../include/pycuda kernel.cu': status 255 invoking 'nvcc --cubin -Wall -arch sm_11 -I/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pycuda-0.94.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/../include/pycuda kernel.cu': nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'Wall'`

The source problem is, that I spent a whole day debugging, because I overlooked an inexplicit conversion from`float` to `int`.

*[Warnings from system-header with "--compiler-options -Wall" since CUDA 3.0](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=163810)

Answer (score 5):

The `-Wall` option is not a `nvcc` compiler option, but rather one that is passed on to the supporting compiler (`g++` or `cl.exe`). You need to pass in the option `--compiler-options -Wall` to indicate to `nvcc` that the option is for the supporting compiler. In you python code:

```
mod = compiler.SourceModule(kernel_code,options=['--compiler-options','-Wall'])
```

`PyCuda` seems to want each option specified as a list item, otherwise it wraps the whole thing in quotes which `nvcc` doesn't like.

Comment: I still get an `nvcc fatal: Unknown option '-compiler-options -Wall'` And I noticed `-Wall` is not listed here: http://camolab.googlecode.com/svn-history/r18/trunk/mycode/cuda/nvcc-help.txt

Comment: You need 2 hyphens in front of `compiler-options`: `--compiler-options`. `-Wall` won't be listed there because it's not and `nvcc` option. As I said in my answer. `nvcc` passes that parameter on to the supporting compiler

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. If I pass `'--compiler-options -Wall'`, there only appears 1 hyphen in the error message. To get two hyphens in the error message, I have to add a third in the function call. I've no idea why that happens.

Comment: See my updated answer. I think that you need to add each one as a separate list item.

Comment: Thanks, that worked so far. But how do I output the return of nvcc? I tried `print repr(mod)`, but it only returned the id. I also did not find anything useful in `dir(mod)`. Anyway +1

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about pyCuda (only about CUDA and C++). I would have a look at the source for the `SourceModule` function to see what it does with the output. Maybe you could modify it to get back the output. From the docs it doesn't look like it allows you to get at it currently

Comment: Oh, thank you for trying. I +1 your comments, so you get some rep from that here.